# How to optimize scan of 1 huge file / table in Hive to confirm/check if lat long point is contained in a wkt geometry shape

Tags: hadoop, hive, geospatial, spatial, hiveql

I am currently trying to associate each lat long ping from a device to its ZIP code.

I have de-normalized lat long device ping data and created a cross-product/ Cartesian product join table in which each row has the ST_Point(long,lat), geometry_shape_of_ZIP and associated zip code for that geometry. for testing purpose I have around 45 million rows in the table and it'll increase in production to about 1 billion every day.

Even though the data is flattened and no join conditions, the query takes about 2 hours to complete. Is there any faster way to compute spatial queries? Or how can I optimize the following query.

Inline is some of the optimizations steps I have already performed. Using the optimizations all the other operations gets done in max 5 minutes except for this one step. I am using aws cluster 2 mater nodes and 5 data nodes.

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;

set hive.execution.engine=tez;

set hive.enforce.sorting=true;

set hive.cbo.enable=true;

set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;

set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;

set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;

analyze table tele_us_zipmatch compute statistics for columns;

CREATE TABLE zipcheck (

`long4` double,

`lat4` double,

state_name string,

country_code string,

country_name string, region string,

zip int,

countyname string) PARTITIONED by (state_id string)

STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY",

'orc.create.index'='true',

'orc.bloom.filter.columns'='');

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE zipcheck PARTITION(state_id)

select long4, lat4, state_name, country_code, country_name, region, zip, countyname, state_id from tele_us_zipmatch

where ST_Contains(wkt_shape,zip_point)=TRUE;
```

ST_Contains is the function from esri (ref: https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Documentation#relationship-tests ).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For you or your organization, is it an option to write custom Java code, for custom map-reduce applications?

Comment: We haven't tried it yet with mapreduce. However, there is nothing stopping us as we write java transformations in informatica. If it speeds up the process we can leverage that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ZIP-code dataset can fit into memory, try a custom Map-Reduce application that uses a just-in-time in-memory quadtree index on the ZIP-code data, by adapting the [sample in the GIS-Tools-for-Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-mr).

[collaborator]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the repository. I will run this asap and get back to you with the result.

Comment: Using the quadTree index worked great! I was able to process over 40 million entries in around 6 minutes in a small test cluster. 
It took some time to make it read wkt and also process muti-polygons, in the end it was worth it. 
I still think the code can be optimized. Will work on that later! Surprised MapReduce worked faster than all hive optimizations.
- Thanks